# Killing processes in Raspbian

Tags: linux, kill, raspbian

I am trying to kill the processes below:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps aux | grep raspi
pi        4647  0.0  0.5   3520  1392 pts/2    S+   12:05   0:00 grep --color=auto raspi
root      8148  0.0  0.5  10744  1372 ?        Sl   06:25   0:00 raspivid -w 800 -h 600 -t 15000 -o /home/pi/media/2015-02-01-06-25-03.177474.h264 -n -rot 270
pi       30099  0.0  0.6  11400  1748 pts/1    Sl+  11:57   0:00 raspistill -o test.jpg
```

I tried some commands as showed below but no success:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pkill -f raspivid
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pkill -f raspistill
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo kill 8148
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo kill 30099
```

I am logged via SSH as the "pi" user, is it the source of issue?
If yes, then why I can't kill my own process (30099)?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of `kill` command family is misleading - they don't really kill anything, just send signals to processes. By default `SIGTERM` signal is sent, which only gently asks process to quit, but process can choose to ignore it or handle it differently. (see [man page for `kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)).

To force-quit a process, you have to send it a `SIGKILL` signal. `SIGKILL` cannot be ignored by the process and in most cases results in its instant termination, without finishing tasks in progress etc.

There are few possible syntaxes to send `SIGKILL`, all of these are completely equivalent:

```
kill -9 <pid>
kill -kill <pid>
kill -s SIGKILL <pid>
```

It's possible that process will be unkillable even with `SIGKILL` and [reboot will be required](https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/).

Answer (score 1):

I killed a python3 script that was started via rc.local with the command:

```bsh
sudo killall python3
```

I first listed all running processes with the command:

```bsh
ps -ef
```